# Security Question for Customer Portal Profile Users

Tags: community, customer-portal

When creating a salesforce User we have seen Security Question & Answer challenge which can be used later on as a security setting for the user.
Can we do this for Customer Portal Profile users as well? 
I think its still under Idea:
 [Customer Portal Security Questions](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000gqlIAAQ)

Any suggestion on this please or any tweak without using any separate metadata or custom code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now there is no second layer security for customer portal but hopefully Salesforce will be releasing this functionality in future releases